# PrettyPhoto annd youtube videos overlay

Tags: youtube, photo, wmode

I have a webpage with prettyPhoto and a youtube video inside the web page.
With jquery I do:

```
    $("#youtubevideo embed").attr("wmode", "opaque"); 
also tried $("#youtubevideo embed").attr("wmode", "transparent");
```

In firefox image is over the youtube video, but the corners of pretty photo are missing. Not really missing because if I scroll up ad down they are shown. But still they don't appear correctly.
In Chrome video is still on top of the images :( Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after 2 days of searching the web for the answer i've found a pure JS function that fix it in all browsers!

there you go:

```
function fix_flash() {
    // loop through every embed tag on the site
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embed = embeds[i];
        var new_embed;
        // everything but Firefox & Konqueror
        if (embed.outerHTML) {
            var html = embed.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")/i))
                new_embed = html.replace(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")window('|")/i, "wmode='transparent'");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_embed = html.replace(/<embed\s/i, "<embed wmode='transparent' ");
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed version
            embed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_embed);
            embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
        } else {
            // cloneNode is buggy in some versions of Safari & Opera, but works fine in FF
            new_embed = embed.cloneNode(true);
            if (!new_embed.getAttribute('wmode') || new_embed.getAttribute('wmode').toLowerCase() == 'window')
                new_embed.setAttribute('wmode', 'transparent');
            embed.parentNode.replaceChild(new_embed, embed);
        }
    }
    // loop through every object tag on the site
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i];
        var new_object;
        // object is an IE specific tag so we can use outerHTML here
        if (object.outerHTML) {
            var html = object.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")\s*\/?\>/i))
                new_object = html.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")window('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_object = html.replace(/<\/object\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />\n</object>");
            // loop through each of the param tags
            var children = object.childNodes;
            for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                try {
                    if (children[j] != null) {
                        var theName = children[j].getAttribute('name');
                        if (theName != null && theName.match(/flashvars/i)) {
                            new_object = new_object.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")flashvars('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[^'"]*('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='flashvars' value='" + children[j].getAttribute('value') + "' />");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            }
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed versiony
            object.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_object);
            object.parentNode.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can just run in when the page loads with jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            fix_flash();    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add `?wmode=transparent` to each youtube link

**So if you have code like:**

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aoZbiS20HGI">
</iframe>
```

**You need to change it to:**

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aoZbiS20HGI?wmode=transparent">
</iframe>
```